# PowerShell Convert .msg to .pdf with attachments

Tags: powershell, pdf, outlook, type-conversion

I have a *large* number of .msg files spread all around a shared drive that need converted to pdf. Adobe Acrobat can't open .msg so we're trying Powershell (vs 5)
I've used the below script to do the conversion, but it leaves out attachments. I would really prefer to have embedded attachments over saving them as separate documents, which is what I've seen most people do. Any ideas?

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter *.msg? | ForEach-Object {

    $msgFullName = $_.FullName
   $docFullName = $msgFullName -replace '\.msg$', '.doc'
    $pdfFullName = $msgFullName -replace '\.msg$', '.pdf'

    $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($msgFullName)
    $msg.SaveAs($docFullName, 4)

    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($docFullName)
    $doc.SaveAs([ref] $pdfFullName, [ref] 17)

    $doc.Close()
 }
```

Comment: These .msg files.... are they Outlook Emails? Those cannot be simply converted to PDF. Are you just trying to extract the attachement within? Or are you trying to convert the email body into a PDF with embedded files which are the attachments of that email?

Comment: Using Outlook COM, Select a PDF printer and call print or set your default printer to the MS PDF printer, then just call print.

Comment: @Matt Yes they are. The script I've included already converts the body of the email to PDF, but it leaves out attachments. Yes, I'm trying to embed the attachments.

Comment: Just embedd every attachment as file? No matter if ZIP MSG jpeg... or xlsx?